# Magento Extension List

Tags: list, magento

I am browsing through all the current Magento extensions via Magento connect. It takes a very long to go page by page through this list and is cumbersome. Is there any API available that gives a list of all the available extensions or a Index list of these extensions.

Your help will be appreciated.